# How to select length of characters and column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this db 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f134/4/0
of which extracts the longest word with points that contained within the word with no points. 
I need to have the column (4th) of the word without points matching per row (that contains the word)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in your question as text tables*.  There is no fourth column in your table, so the question is quite unclear.

Comment: the 4 column here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f134/4/0  would have first row with 'stone road and etc' and 2ed row with 'tool box online 2019', each max 1 point word with max 0 point word. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the matching phrase (without points) for each row that has points.  `APPLY` is useful in this situation:

```
SELECT w.id, w.phrase, w.points, w2.phrase
FROM words w OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) w2.*
      FROM words w2
      WHERE w2.phrase LIKE concat('%', w.phrase, '%') and w2.points = 0
      ORDER BY len(w2.phrase) DESC
     ) w2
WHERE w.points > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=301b868d2200671c184825b96978837f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon Linoff  Thanks for the answer, I meant that I need a 4th column with the matching phrase with 0 points

Comment: @refaelo1979 . . . That is what this code does.  Did you see the db<>fiddle?

Comment: Yes, Gordon Linoff thanks, it's just that only the longest phrases in both columns should be extracted so it should be kind of a combination of the query I have in here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f134/4/0 and the one db<>fiddle you have showed, much appreciated for your help